# Виджет не сохраняется в сайдбаре (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, виджет

Предо мной стала такая задача, как создать плагин, который будет создавать виджет, выполняющий определенные функции. А именно - выводить список юзеров из базы данных. 
Собственно, сама проблема заключается в том, что виджет, созданный плагином, после обновления - исчезает из сайдбара.

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Название плагина
Plugin URI: http://страница_с_описанием_плагина_и_его_обновлений
Description: Краткое описание плагина.
Version: Номер версии плагина, например: 1.0
Author: Имя автора плагина
Author URI: http://страница_автора_плагина
*/
/**
 * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
*/
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {
/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'foo_widget', // Base ID
        esc_html__( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
        array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}

/**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
    }
    echo esc_html__( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
/**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 *
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    ?>  
    <p>
       <?php
        global $wpdb;

    $postCnt = intval($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_users")); //кол-во юзеров .

    ?>

    <form action="" method = "POST">
        <input type="checkbox" name = "allU"><label >Все пользователи</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name = "UWC"><label>Пользователи, оставившие комментарий</label><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name = "UWTC"><label>Пользователи, не оставившие комментариев</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name = "COM" checked><label>Показывать комментарии</label>
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
        <input type="number" min="1" max="<?php echo $postCnt ?>" value="1" name="usrscnt">
    </form>

    <ul>
        <?php 
        $itsAll = isset($_POST['allU']);
        $itsWC = isset($_POST['UWC']);
        $itsWTC = isset($_POST['UWTC']);
        $itsCOM = isset($_POST['COM']);
        $wu = $_POST['usrscnt'];


        $i = 1; //intval($wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM wp_users" ))
        $j = 1;
        $m = 1;

        if($itsAll){
            while($i <= $wu){
                    $author = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_nicename FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '$i'" );
                    $cc = intval($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_author = '$author'"));
                    if($itsCOM){
                           echo "<li style= \"list-style:none;\">".$i.") <u>".$author."</u>  |  <i>Count of comments: </i><b style = \"font-weight:bold\">".$cc."</b></li>";

                        }
                        else{
                        echo "<li style= \"list-style:none;\">".$i.") <u>".$author."</u></li>";

                        }
                    $i++;
            }   
        }
        if($itsWC){
            while($i <= $wu){
                    $author = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_nicename FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '$i'" );
                    $cc = intval($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_author = '$author'"));
                    if($cc > 0){
                        if($itsCOM){
                           echo "<li style= \"list-style:none;\">".$j.") <u>".$author."</u>  |  <i>Count of comments: </i><b style = \"font-weight:bold\">".$cc."</b></li>";
                        $j++; 
                        }
                        else{
                        echo "<li style= \"list-style:none;\">".$j.") <u>".$author."</u></li>";
                        $j++; 
                        }
                    }
                    $i++;
            }   
        }

        if($itsWTC){
            while($i <= $wu){
                    $author = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT user_nicename FROM wp_users WHERE ID = '$i'" );
                    $cc = intval($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_author = '$author'"));
                   if($cc == 0){
                        if($itsCOM){
                           echo "<li style= \"list-style:none;\">".$j.") <u>".$author."</u>  |  <i>Count of comments: </i><b style = \"font-weight:bold\">".$cc."</b></li>";
                        $j++; 
                        }
                        else{
                        echo "<li style= \"list-style:none;\">".$j.") <u>".$author."</u></li>";
                        $j++; 
                        }
                    }
                    $i++;
            }   
        }
        ?>


    </ul>
    </ul>
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
}

} // class Foo_Widget

// register Foo_Widget widget
function register_foo_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );

?>
```

Есть еще такой момент, что если поместить внутрь плагина чистую болванку, то оно всё сохранит.

```
<?php 

/*
Plugin Name: Название плагина
Plugin URI: http://страница_с_описанием_плагина_и_его_обновлений
Description: Краткое описание плагина.
Version: Номер версии плагина, например: 1.0
Author: Имя автора плагина
Author URI: http://страница_автора_плагина
*/

/**
 * Adds Foo_Widget widget.
 */
class Foo_Widget extends WP_Widget {

/**
 * Register widget with WordPress.
 */
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        'foo_widget', // Base ID
        esc_html__( 'Widget Title', 'text_domain' ), // Name
        array( 'description' => esc_html__( 'A Foo Widget', 'text_domain' ), ) // Args
    );
}

/**
 * Front-end display of widget.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::widget()
 *
 * @param array $args     Widget arguments.
 * @param array $instance Saved values from database.
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] ) . $args['after_title'];
    }
    echo esc_html__( 'Hello, World!', 'text_domain' );
    echo $args['after_widget'];
}

/**
 * Back-end widget form.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::form()
 *
 * @param array $instance Previously saved values from database.
 */
public function form( $instance ) {
    $title = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : esc_html__( 'New title', 'text_domain' );
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title:', 'text_domain' ); ?></label> 
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>">
    </p>
    <?php 
}

/**
 * Sanitize widget form values as they are saved.
 *
 * @see WP_Widget::update()
 *
 * @param array $new_instance Values just sent to be saved.
 * @param array $old_instance Previously saved values from database.
 *
 * @return array Updated safe values to be saved.
 */
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();
    $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

    return $instance;
}

} // class Foo_Widget

// register Foo_Widget widget
function register_foo_widget() {
    register_widget( 'Foo_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_foo_widget' );

?>
```

То есть, не сохраняет только при наличии кастомного пхп-кода.

А в случае, если поместить болванку и перезаписать её кастомным, то оно сохранит, до первой смены темы или деактивации плагина.

Можете указать на ошибки в моем коде ?

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Непохоже, что ваш код может препятствовать сохранению виджета. В нем ничего подозрительного нет. В какой версии WordPress пытаетесь сохранить? До 4.9, насколько помню, была проблема с сохранением виджетов.

Comment: Пользуюсь версией 5.23 .